# pip install .whl on server without internet with all dependency .whl files in same folder

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-wheel

To install a non native python .whl file on server without internet I go for below route

1. On desktop with internet use pip download to get .whl file
2. Some .whl files required many other .whl files example bokeh
3. Copy all .whi files (example bokeh and all it's dependency files) in a folder
4. On server start installing .whl files 1 by 1 like below
   pip install typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl

Can I somehow request pip to look for dependency .whl files in same folder so I fire below and all dependency .whl gets installed ?
pip install bokeh-2.4.3-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: `pip install --no-index --find-links . bokeh-2.4.3-py3-none-any.whl`. The dot in `--find-links .` means "the current directory.".